# Can I use elasticsearch to map many different keys

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, my json data likes this:

```
{
    "noveltitle_1": {
         "title": " ... ",
         "author": " ... ",
         "text": "..."
    }
    "noveltitle_2": {
         "title": " ... ",
         "author": " ... ",
         "text": "..."
    }
    ...
    "noveltitle_n": {
         "title": " ... ",
         "author": " ... ",
         "text": "..."
    }
}
```

I want to mapping these data by using elasticsearch, what should I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I want to mapping these json data. I know if the key is unique, I can write mapping like this :
{
   "novel":{
           "properties": {
                   "title": {"type": "string"},
                   "author": {"type": "string"},
                   "text": {"type": "string"}
}

but now the keys are not unique, so how to mapping the json data ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this some 3rd party data which you don't have control over ? Will it not be better to structure your data like:

```
{   "novels":[
 {
     "title": "noveltitle_1",
     "author": " ... ",
     "text": "..."
}
 {
     "title": "noveltitle_2",
     "author": " ... ",
     "text": "..."
}
 {
     "title": "noveltitle_3",
     "author": " ... ",
     "text": "..."
}    ] }
```

This will allow you to search for novel based on title, author or text.